# div class show/hide on selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a little issue in my javascript and html code. When I select `10`  from dropdown box than `<div class="tab-pane text-style">` should be show, but when I select 25 from dropdown box this class should not be show.
Here is my selected drop down box code

```
<div class="">Show
  <select id="dropDown">
    <option value="page5">10</option>
    <option value="page7">25</option>
    <option value="page6">50</option>
    <option value="page8">100</option>
    <option value="page9">All</option>
  </select>
records per page</div>
```

Here is my `div class="tab-pane text-style"` code:

```
<div class="tab-pane text-style" id="page0" >
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pagination pull-right" id='0'>
    <li ><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"id="link1" onClick="pagi1()">1</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#"id="link2" onClick="pagi2()">2</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#"id="link3" onClick="pagi3()">3</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#"id="link4" onClick="pagi4()">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'page5')
      {
        $("#page0").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#page0").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Please help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropDown').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'page5')
      {
        $("#page0").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#page0").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: lazy to explain? Hopefully Alok did.

Answer (score 3):

The id the change event handler is `dropdown` instead of `dropDown`
Change it and you re good to go.
Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v6nmbo5k/1/)

Answer (score 2):

ID's are case sensitive. In HTML your select has id 'dropDown', while in js you bind event to 'dropdown'. Unifying names should help.